# is a==null? brach1 : branch2 - not lazy evaluated in java?

Tags: java, syntax

how can i get null pointer exception from this line of code?

```
String a = "localUri: "+  mCurrentImageUri == null? "none" : mCurrentImageUri.toString();
```

`mCurrentImageUri == null`, but I have thought it won't evaluate `mCurrentImageUri.toString()` if so

half-related:

how to write similar to this c# syntax?

string a = `myVar?? "none"`

Comment: What is the type of myVar in C# ?

Comment: Note that `+` has higher precedence than `==`, so `"localUri: "+  mCurrentImageUri == null` really means: `("localUri: "+  mCurrentImageUri) == null`, which is not what you meant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
"localUri: " + (mCurrentImageUri == null ? "none" : mCurrentImageUri.toString())
```

Without parentheses, it's parsed as `(("localUri: "+ mCurrentImageUri) == null) ? ...`, which is always false.

Comment: Your paratheses are wrong.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I hope you don't mean SLaks, because this answer is right.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: Yes, I mean his answer. The ternary conditional operator takes a boolean expression as first operand.

Comment: should have been `("localUri: "+ mCurrentImageUri) == null`

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: And therefore what?

Comment: `"localUri: "+ mCurrentImageUri == null` is still a boolean.

Comment: @SLaks: Still wrong. I'm pointing to the expression that it is like without adding the extra paratheses.

Comment: @SLaks The point is that in that second statement, with those parens, if the OP thought that `==` had higher precedence, it would still look right.  That example is ambiguous as to which is run first, unless you know the operator precedence.  By changing it to `(localUri: " + mCurrentImageUri)` it makes it clear to the reader that it's wrong.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: Jesper is right.

Comment: @Selman22: That's exactly the problem.

Comment: @SLaks: But... The conditional operator syntax is: *boolean ? expr1 : expr2*. Your first operand is a String, instead of a boolean. Look at Jesper his comment.

Comment: I added more parentheses to clarify the order of operations.

Comment: I'm withdrawing my comment, since I thought OP was asking about C#. I see now that this is Java, which I can't speak about with confidence.

Comment: @SLaks: Ow... I'm wondering. What has higher precedence? `+` or `==`? Maybe they are evaluated left to right. If so, I was wrong.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: `+` has higher precedence than `==`.  To put it differently, `if (a + b == 5)` will do what you think it does.

Comment: @SLaks yeah I noticed that I don't mean you,I meant jasper, your answer is correct

Comment: @SLaks: I'm experiencing it different: http://ideone.com/9ltqH9. The fact that this doesn't compile means that we have a String as result.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux He didn't fix it.  It was correct before.  The whole point of the question is that `+` has higher precedence to `==`, so the addition is done first, then the equality check, so the whole expression resolves to a boolean, not a string, and is always true.  After the edit it's *clearer*, but it was always *correct*.

Comment: @SLaks: Please check out my answer. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

As to the Java code, as others pointed out,  
what you have written in Java is equivalent to:

```
String a = ("localUri: " +  mCurrentImageUri == null ) ? "none" : mCurrentImageUri.toString();
```

and that's why you get the NullPointerException (NPE).

In C# you can just do:

```
myVar == null ? "none" : myVar.ToString()
```

The syntax is quite similar to Java
( in Java you have toString(), in C# you have ToString() )

In C#, as you suggested, you can also use the 
left coalesce operator. For more details, check here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: You mean in Java, right?

Comment: No, I meant in C#, the syntax is not much different.

Comment: @peter.petrov This is a java question, not a C# question.

Comment: Then this was not relevant before the java part.

Comment: @Servy I was answering this "how to write similar to this c# syntax?"

Answer (score 1):

> how can i get null pointer exception from this line of code?

If you look the table operators precedence `+` has a higher precedence than the ternary operator, so you concatenate your string first then it's not null so you go in the second condition.